# How to send intent of the full listview

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've got a list of items. I need to send intent in another app with ALL items in the list. I have found information only about selected item

```
 private void insertPet() {

    Log.v(TAG, "Создали insertpet");

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    String shareBody = "Body here";
    String shareSub = "Sub here";
    myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareSub);
    myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    myIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share using"));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putParcelableArrayListExtra?

Comment: Can you post the type of your list? Is it a standard ArrayList<String> ?

Answer (score 1):

For passing a simple ArrayList of Strings you can use StringArrayListExtra.

To pass an ArrayList:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();  
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("test", (ArrayList<String>) test);
```

To Retrieve an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> test = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by a List as something like this,

```
List<SomeObject> list;
```

Then, you can give it to an intent by doing this.

First, your object must implement Seriablizable.

```
public class SomeObject implements Serializable{...}
```

Second, put the list of items inside the intent as a serializable list.

```
    intent.putExtra("list", (Serializable) list);
```

Answer (score 0):

To share multiple pieces of content, use the ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE action together with a list of URIs pointing to the content.

```
ArrayList<Uri> myintent = new ArrayList<Uri>();
myintent.add(item1); // Add your List
myintent.add(item2);

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,myintent );
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share using"));
```

As before, make sure the provided URIs point to data that a receiving application can access.

Answer (score 0):

1.Implement Parcelable in your POJO Class.
2. Use below code

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
ArrayList<YourPOJO> list=new ArrayList<>();
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("List",list)// modify
myIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share using"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First give the ListView Item custom Layout a id in XML file like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
     android:layout_margin="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/LayoutSize"
    android:padding="5dp">

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your custom Adaptor add a `OnClickListener` on linearLayout like -

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            insertPet();
        }
    });
```